# swift 3 - subclassed view controller not being displayed

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, swift3, subclass, viewcontroller

In my Swift 3/Obj-C application, I'm having trouble displayed a swift view controller, that is subclassed from and Obj-C class.

The following code works perfectly:

**NavigationController.swift**

```
func myMethod(){
    ...
    let vc = ParentViewController.init(someParameter: parameter) // << results in desired screen
    vc?.stringProperty = "someString"
    self.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

**SuperParentViewController.h**

```
@interface SuperParentViewController : UIViewController 
     @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringProperty;
     - (instancetype)initWithSomeParameter:(SomeClass *)someParameter;
@end
```

**ParentViewController.h**

```
@interface ParentViewController : SuperParentViewController
     // numerous properties are declared here
@end
```

**ParentViewController.m**

```
@implementation ParentViewController
    ...

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // a bunch of properties are set
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        // more properties are set
    }

    ...
@end
```

But, if I subclass ParentViewController and try to present the subclass, "SubclassViewController", this results in a screen that has only the navigation bar items displayed; the rest of the screen is blank:

**NavigationController.swift**

```
func myMethod(){
    ...
    let vc = SubClassedViewController.init(someParameter: parameter) // << results in blank screen
    vc?.stringProperty = "someString"
    self.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

**SubClassedViewController.swift**

```
class SubClassedViewController: ParentViewController
{
    // nothing in this file yet
}
```

Can somebody tell me why SubClassedViewController is failing to display the same contents of ParentViewController?

Comment: I would check to see if all of the view cycle methods in your super classes are being called. Also, it may be helpful to look at the View Hierarchy within Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ParentViewController was associated with an .xib file (Click .xib file -> go to Identify Inspector -> Under Custom Class, you will find "ParentViewController").  Thus, when subclassing ParentViewController to create the SubClassedViewController class, I needed to also use the following code to initialize the same .xib file:

**(Swift 3)**

```
class SubClassedViewController: ParentViewController
{    
    override init(someParameter: someClass) {
        super.init(nibName: "ParentViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```